# Different template for adding data and editing data on a Telerik grid

Tags: vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to pass a different template to a Telerik Grid, depending on if the add button or the edit button is pressed (on creation: a few field to fill. on existing: add button : some extra fields to fill, edit button : most field are read-only, new field to fill).

```
Dim myGrid = Html.Telerik().Grid(Of SomeModel) _
.Name("myGrid")

    If Model.Action = AddNewData Then
        myGrid.Editable(Sub(editing) _  
        editing.Enabled(True).Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(False) _
        .TemplateName("AddTemplate"))

    ElseIf Model.Action = EditOldData Then
      if "gridBoutonPushed = Add" then
        grille.Editable(Sub(editing) _
        editing.Enabled(True).Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(False) _
        .TemplateName("EditTemplateNew"))
      else 'edit button was pushed
        grille.Editable(Sub(editing) _
        editing.Enabled(True).Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(False) _
        .TemplateName("EditTemplateOld"))
      end if
    End If

'generate the add button
myGrid.ToolBar(Sub(c) c.Template(" <a href='#' class='t-button t-button-icontext t-grid-add'>" &
                    "<span style='margin-left: 0pt;' class='t-icon t-add'></span>Add stuff</a>"))
```

I have no idea on how to do the `if "gridBoutonPushed = Add" then` part. Any Suggestions?
... I'm also open to other way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had a similar issue and came up with a workaround using javascript and Telerik's action handlers
First i added this to the Grid's property set:

```
.ClientEvents(Function(events) events.OnEdit("onEditUsers"))
```

which points the handler to this function then outside of the grid code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onEditUsers(e) {

           var popup = $("#" + e.currentTarget.id + "PopUp");
           var popupDataWin = popup.data("tWindow");


           if (e.mode == "insert") {
               //for creating
               popupDataWin.title("Add new User");

           }
           else {
               //for editing
               popupDataWin.title("Edit Customer");

               // Hide fields from the pop-up.
               $(e.form).find("#UnwantedField1").closest(".editor-field").prev().andSelf().hide();
               $(e.form).find("#UnwantedField2").closest(".editor-field").prev().andSelf().hide();
           }
       }
   </script>
```

You may be able to modify these function to make the fields behave as you require

Unfortunately this requires your templates to all exist in one file, and requires you to define which fields behave which way for each different event

I hope this helps!